# fxml - Reading value from properties

Tags: java, javafx, properties, fxml

I new to **fxml** and i am still trying to sort some things out. Normally, when i am developing, i create some ***.properties file that i use to read values from.**

This is what i normally do:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/configuration/someproject/properties/project.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Then i just read whatever value i want when i am declaring my beans. Something like this:

```
<bean id="test" class="my.package.MyClass">
    <property name="variable" value="${some.value}" />
</bean>
```

Now, i've been searching how to do something like this in fxml but i can't seem to find anything.
I apologize for being to noob at this, but is it possible to do this kind of things with fxml?

For example, in the following code, is it possible to define the url of the image externally:

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER" styleClass="header" stylesheets="@../styles/some.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane>
         <children>
              <ImageView AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="22.0">
                  <image>
                      <Image url="@../img/image.png" />
                  </image>
              </ImageView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
```

**PS**: I am trying to develop a standalone app but still i would like to configure some values externally without having to generate a new build anytime i need to change something.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using Spring in your JavaFX application, or was that just an example for comparison?

Comment: @James_D this is just an example for comparison...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to do this is by assigning a resource bundle in the FXMLLoader.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("propertyreader.application"));
Parent root = loader.load(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "about.fxml"
    )
);
```

The syntax for access is slightly different (uses a `%` instead of `${`).

```
<Label fx:id="version" text="%version"/>
```

**Sample App**

The sample app assumes that all files are in a package named `propertyreader`.

[image: property reader pic]

*application.properties*

```
version=1
```

*about.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Label text="Property Reader Version:"/>
    <Label fx:id="version" text="%version"/>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
</HBox>
```

*PropertyReaderApp.java*

```
package propertyreader;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class PropertyReaderApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("propertyreader.application"));
        Parent root = loader.load(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "about.fxml"
            )
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. With your answer  and James_D answer i feel i can do a good job developing the application. Again, thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this, but I haven't seen much (any) documentation on it. The trick is to access the `FXMLLoader`'s [`namespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getNamespace--) and populate it with the properties, before loading the FXML.

Given a property file application.properties:

```
foo=bar
```

You can do:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Path propFile = Paths.get("application.properties"); 
properties.load(Files.newBufferedReader(propFile));

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
properties.stringPropertyNames()
    .forEach(key -> loader.getNamespace().put(key, properties.getProperty(key)));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Then in your FXML file you can access the properties with, e.g.

```
<Label text="${foo}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you :-)

Comment: Why not simply say ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings"); /* strings is in a file called strings.properties*/
            
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"), bundle);
and then just access the key names using % like the answer below?